# Copying big amount of data in VBA excel

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I would like to be able to copy around 30k rows (to be exact, just some elements of the rows) from sheet A to sheet B, starting the destination from row nr 36155. Sometimes, we copy the row more than once, depending on the number in the G column. This is the macro I've written:

```
Sub copy()
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculate

Dim k As Long, k1 As Long, i As Integer

k = 36155
k1 = 30000

For i = 1 To k1
For j = 1 To Sheets("A").Range("G" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("A" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("A" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("B" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("B" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("C" & k).Value = j
    Sheets("B").Range("D" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("C" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("E" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("D" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("F" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("E" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("G" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("F" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("H" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("I" & i + 2).Value + (j - 1) * Sheets("A").Range("H" & i + 2).Value
    Sheets("B").Range("I" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("J" & i + 2).Value
    k = k + 1
Next j
Next i


Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this macro takes a lot of time to run (around 10 minutes). I have a feeling that, there may be a better way to do that.. Do you have any ideas, how can we enchance the macro?

Comment: The first thing you could try is to turn auto-calculation off before the loop and set if back to on after it. This may save you a lot of time.

Comment: By the way, how many times (average) you copy the same record (i.e. the average number of times the inner loop runs for each cycle of the outer loop)?

Comment: Use the `Variant Array` technique.  There are plenty of examples on SO

Comment: @FDavidov the calculation in my excel is manual, that's why I've included  Application.calculate in my code. On average, i copy the same record around 5 times. but I still think the macro should not work so long..

Comment: Agree with the time estimation (too long) but don't agree with the calculation. Set it as disable, test it, and let me know if the result is still OK and how long it took.

Comment: @FDavidov I am affraid I don't understand. Manual calculation mode == Disabled calculation (for me). Is there a difference?

Comment: In your code you have `Application.Calculate` while you should have `Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual` and then `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` at the end. Again, if you try this, please share your results.

Comment: @FDavidov Application.Calculate calculates the workbook (and I have to use it, because my workbook is already in xlCalculateManual mode - as in my workbook_open() macro I set this up to be this way). To be sure, I have checked what you asked, but it made no difference

Comment: I see. Hummm... Interesting. Frankly, your codes does not look as "highly inefficient" as to take that much time to complete. There is one more thing I would try (no promise it would make any difference though): Revert the order of the loops, i.e. make the OUTER look to be the INNER one. This might not yield the correct result but would hint if there is an issue with the code (performance-wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using variant arrays: could be even faster if you can use a B array containing more than 1 row. This version takes 17 seconds on my PC.

```
Sub Copy2()
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculate
    '
    Dim k As Long, k1 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim varAdata As Variant
    Dim varBdata() As Variant
    '
    Dim dT As Double
    '
    dT = Now()
    '
    k = 36155
    k1 = 30000
    '
    ' get sheet A data into variant array
    '
    varAdata = Worksheets("A").Range("A1:J1").Resize(k1 + 2).Value2
    '
    For i = 1 To k1
        'For j = 1 To Sheets("A").Range("G" & i + 2).Value
        For j = 1 To varAdata(i + 2, 7)
            '
            ' create empty row of data for sheet B and  fill from variant array of A data
            '
            ReDim varBdata(1 to 1,1 to 9) As Variant
            'Sheets("B").Range("A" & k).Value = Sheets("A").Range("A" & i + 2).Value
            varBdata(1, 1) = varAdata(i + 2, 1)
            varBdata(1, 2) = varAdata(i + 2, 2)
            varBdata(1, 3) = j
            varBdata(1, 4) = varAdata(i + 2, 3)
            varBdata(1, 5) = varAdata(i + 2, 4)
            varBdata(1, 6) = varAdata(i + 2, 5)
            varBdata(1, 7) = varAdata(i + 2, 6)
            varBdata(1, 8) = varAdata(i + 2, 9) + (j - 1) * varAdata(i + 2, 8)
            varBdata(1, 9) = varAdata(i + 2, 10)
            '
            ' write to sheet B
            '
            Sheets("B").Range("A1:I1").Offset(k - 1).Value2 = varBdata
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    '
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox (Now() - dT)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you read your data into a recordset [as shown here](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/), then loop the recordset.

Try the following (untested).

```
Sub copy()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculate
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim k As Long, i As Integer

    k = 36155

    ' read data into a recordset
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = GetRecordset(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A").UsedRange) 'feel free to hard-code your range here

    With rst
        While Not .EOF

            For j = 1 To !FieldG
          ' !FieldG accesses the Datafield with the header "FieldG". Change this to the header you actually got in Column G, like "!MyColumnG" or ![columnG with blanks]

                Sheets("B").Cells(k, 1).Value = !FieldA
                ' ... your code

                k = k + 1
            Next j

            .movenext
        Wend

    End With


    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Also add the following Function into your VBA Module.

```
Function GetRecordset(rng As Range) As Object

    'Recordset ohne Connection:
    'https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/

    Dim xlXML As Object
    Dim rst As Object

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)

    rst.Open xlXML

    Set GetRecordset = rst

End Function
```

**Note:** 
- using a recordset gives you additional options like filtering data
- with a recordset, your not dependent on the column-order of your input-data, meaning you don't have to adjust your macro if you decide to add another column to sheet A (as long as you keep the headers the same)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That open Xml as a recordset is an extremely interesting trick, not something I've seen before and one to keep at the back of one's mind.  Thanks!  However for this problem a variant array copy, i.e. using Value or Value2 as both bulk getter and bulk setter is fastest.

Comment: Glad you found it useful - by far the most useful snipped I stumbled upon. [https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/]